# Name of cartoon that had kids that shrunk down and rode bugs

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animation

Here are the details and things I remember about it:

1. This was back around 2012-13, 2014 at the very latest.
2. It was animated, I am pretty sure it was a cartoon and not anime.
3. I think it was French(although I saw it online and in the USA).
4. I think it had little to not dialogue, but I may be misremembering.
5. It followed a group of kids that somehow shrunk down to the size of bugs and rode a butterfly I believe. It might been them playing makebelieve, but I cannot remember. I also think it was in one of their backyards it took place in.
6. I am pretty sure it was not a standalone and had a few other episodes, but I cannot remember them or their titles.